# complex paratition sum in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables as follow:

`A` deliveries

```
delveryid clientid deliverydate
1           10    2015-01-01
2           10    2015-02-02
3           11    2015-04-08
```

`B`   items in deliveris

```
itemid deliveryid qty  status
70        1       5     1
70        1       8     2
70        2       10    1
72        1       12    1
70        3      100    1
```

I need to add a column to my query that gives me the qty of each part in other deliveris of the same client.

meaning that for given data of `client 10` and delivery `id 1` I need to show:

```
itemid  qty  status  qtyOther
70       5     1       10        //itemid 70 exists in delivery 2
70       8     2       10       //itemid 70 exists in delivery 2
72       12    1        0       //itemid 72 doesn't exists in other delivery of client 11
```

Since I need to add `qtyOther` to my existing qry i'm trying to avoid using Group By as it's a huge query and if I use `SUM` in select I will have to group by all items in select.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select ....., coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid) ,0) AS qtyOther
FROM B b   
LEFT JOIN A a USING 
LEFT JOIN (other tables)
WHERE clientid=10 ....
```

This query gives me the total sum of `qty` per `itemid` for specific `clientid`, regardless of which delivery it is.  How do I change it so it will consider the delivryid? I need something like:

```
coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid) FROM B where deliveryid<>b.deliveryid ,0) AS qtyOther
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Note: I can NOT change the condition in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to subtract out the total for the current delivery:

```
Select .....,
       (coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid), 0) -
        coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid, a.deliveryid), 0)
       ) as qtyOther
```